# .txt delete lines containing

Tags: text

There are two text files: 1.txt and 2.txt. 1.txt contains URLs separated by line breaks and 2.txt contains words separated by line breaks, one word per line. I want to delete URLs from 1.txt that contain words from 2.txt. What is the most convenient way to do that?
For example:

**1.txt:**

```
website1.com  
website2word1.com  
webword2site3.com
```

**2.txt:**

```
word1  
word2
```

After processing, 1.txt should look like this:

```
website1.com
```

The files are quite large. The first file contains a million lines (that's after being split, there are multiple files) and the second one contains 10,000 lines.

Comment: And your question is ....?

Comment: what programming language should be used for this script?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a java program to read url from 1.txt and match it with 2.txt. And write the url in 3.txt if matches the requirement.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be the other way round? IE iterate through `2.txt` looking for matches in `1.txt`?